# PaintTo doesn't work with my component

Tags: delphi

Hi all
I made a new component derived from `TWinControl`.
I put it on a `TPanel` and I tried to call the `PaintTo` procedure of the panel. The result is the panel and its caption and my component is not painted on the canvas at all. What should I do about this?

a part of the source (as dear David asked):

```
Procedure TApListBox.Paint;
var
  C: TCanvas;
  B: TBitmap;
  ItemClient: TPoint;
Begin
  Try
    If (FUpdating > 0) Then
      Exit;
    Try
      BeginUpdate;
      B := TBitmap.Create;
      B.Width := Width;
      B.Height := Height;
      With B.Canvas Do Begin
        Lock;
        // Begin :
        ItemClient := Point(IVisPanel + 3, 2);

        // Draw Items
        PaintItems(B.Canvas, ItemClient);
        Unlock;
      End;

      C := TCanvas.Create;
      C.Handle := GetWindowDC(Self.Handle);
      C.Lock;
      inherited;
      C.Draw(1, 1, B);
      If (RenameEdit.Visible) Then
        RenameEdit.Repaint;
    Finally
      C.Unlock;
      ReleaseDC(0, C.Handle);
      C.Free;
      B.Free;
      Dec(FUpdating);
    End;
  Except
  End;
End;
```

Comment: How does your control paint itself?

Comment: If the panel, its caption, *and* your control aren't painted, why do you think the problem is with your control and not the panel?

Comment: Are you using the 'canvas' overload? Or if you're using the 'DC' overload and passing a Canvas' handle to it, are you locking the canvas?

Comment: My control works perfect. Only PaintTo can not be used for it. and I didn't override Paint method; instead I handled WM_PAINT.

Comment: If your control really worked perfectly, then you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: @Rob: I meant all the functions work well, and even it's painted well enough. Only PaintTo is not working so I asked this question!

Comment: @Javid did moving the painting from WM_PAINT to Paint solve your problem?

Comment: @David: No, not actually. I tried to derive it from TCustomControl but it still doesn't work. I wish it was possible to override PaintTo but unfortunately it's not!

Comment: @Javid You derived you control from TCustomControl and moved the painting from WM_PAINT into Paint?

Comment: @David: Yes. Into overridden paint.

Comment: @Javid Could you post your new Paint routine for us please?

Comment: @David: Well, I can't give the full source but just a part of it.

Comment: @Javid try that and let's see if it helps

Comment: @David: I feel it'd help because I think my code is not correct.

Comment: @Javid I think there are probably a number of areas in this code which would benefit from some improvements. However, I think your immediate problem is that you are painting to `GetWindowDC(Self.Handle)`. You just need to draw on the controls own Canvas property. So delete the local variable C and replace `C.Draw(1, 1, B)` with `Canvas.Draw(1, 1, B)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method handling the WM_PAINT message, you can NOT use the Canvas directly, because WM_PAINT specify a GDI handle (HDC) in the Message.DC parameter.

Take a look, for example, at this code snippet from TGraphicControl, which handle it as expected:

```
procedure TGraphicControl.WMPaint(var Message: TWMPaint);
begin
  if Message.DC <> 0 then
  begin
    Canvas.Lock;
    try
      Canvas.Handle := Message.DC;
      try
        Paint; // this is where the painting is done, using a "locked" Canvas
      finally
        Canvas.Handle := 0;
      end;
    finally
      Canvas.Unlock;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

So check your WM_PAINT implementation method, and follow this code scheme.

Instead of the "Paint" method above, put your own drawing code using the Canvas property.

The "PaintTo" method will work as expected.

Another possibility is to use direct Windows API drawings, using the Message.DC handle... but I guess the above method, allowing the use of a regular Canvas, is more easy for most of us! ;)

In all cases, WM_PAINT shouldn't be the place where Delphi components implement the painting, but only an overridden Paint method. So let your component inherits from TGraphicControl, and put all the drawing code into an overridden Paint method.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't ever need to call or override PaintTo.

Instead, you should do 100% of your painting in an overridden Paint method.  Painting can happen at any time, and a component needs to be able to paint itself on demand.  The way that happens is Windows sends a WM_PAINT message which the VCL translates into a call to your component's Paint method.

So make sure your component can paint what it needs to at any time, and **do all of your painting in the overridden Paint Method**.

Comment: I didn't get the feeling that Javid was implementing his paint in PaintTo. I was more of the feeling that he was calling PaintTo because he wanted to get his control to draw to a canvas (which is why PaintTo is there). But I could be wrong!

Comment: David is right. My control works perfect. Only PaintTo can not be used for it.

Comment: PaintTo is sometimes very useful, when you work on reporting, and embed some components into a meta file content. But you're right about the fact that WM_PAINT shouldn't be the place where Delphi components implement the painting, but only an overriden Paint method.

Answer (score 1):

Your base class should be `TCustomControl`, not `TWinControl`. The former sets up the control's canvas so you can paint to it properly by overriding `Paint`.

If you insist on handling `wm_Paint` yourself, make sure you use the `WParam` parameter as the display context, if it's provided. Formally, that parameter is unused, but the VCL (and some common controls) use that for the DC, which makes implementing the `wm_PrintClient` message easier.